# Х без мыши, или mouse jail, или?.. подробности

Tags: linux

Этот вопрос гугленьем я не решил однозначно, поэтому прошу совета. Именно совета, а не прямого решения.

Есть `Хvesa` без оконного менеджера, в ней висит `dosbox`.
`Х` почему-то всегда запускается с мышью, даже когда я намеренно убираю мышиные параметры из строки запуска в `.xsession` . И это мешает, потому что в `Xvesa` по умолчанию (без менеджера, очевидно) та забавная система фокусировки, когда регион получает фокус только когда курсор мыши находится в нем. Стоит отвести мышь в сторону от окна - и любое управление с клавиатуры замораживается. Можно ли заставить `Xvesa` использовать другой алгоритм фокусировки без использования менеджера, я тоже не нашел в гугле. Вдобавок y мыши два курсора: один снаружи "коробки", другой внутри. Когда один подходит к границе, то застывает рядом с ней, а второй "оживает" и продолжает движение. Залочить курсор внутри `dosbox` не получается, возможно, потому что это должен делать менеджер окон.

**Вот и вопрос. Что лучше:**

- Использовать чей-то самописный скрипт или бинарник, реализующий принцип `mouse jail`, ограничивающий движение мыши в заданном регионе.
- Использовать более "официальный" `xdotool`.
- Запустить Xvesa *без мыши*, чтобы она инициализировалась только в `dosbox`. Если да, то как?

Второму варианту я не доверяю, т.к. в голове почему-то отложилось, что `xdotool` делает вещи неоптимально и может давать слишком большую нагрузку для маленькой задачи. Не то, чтобы у меня может чего-то не хватить, но я потому и пытаюсь все сделать так, как делаю, чтобы ради собственного удовольствия обойтись наименьшими ресурсами. Сейчас система жрет 40 Мб ОЗУ, куда уж больше. `xdotool`, скорее, будет процессор нагружать, но это тоже нежелательно.
Первому варианту по этим же причинам стоит не доверять еще больше, т.к. мало ли кто там как это писал. Может, там вообще утечка памяти будет. :)
Ну а с третьим попросту не понятно, так как его-то я уже пробовал: удалил параметры **-2button -mouse** из аргументов `Xvesa`. А он все равно запускается с мышью.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

справедливо для «полноценного» *xserver-а*. как будет себя вести *xvesa* — не знаю. проще всего проверить.

1.

мышь можно «обездвижить» (и отключить кнопки), например, с помощью [`xinput`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/xinput). показываю на примере.

список устройств-pointer-ов (тут не мышь, а `trackpad`, что несущественно):

```
$ xinput --list | grep pointer
| Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
| ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
| ↳ Cypress APA Trackpad (cyapa)                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

`id` у нужного устройства — `12` (но надёжнее обращаться по имени `Cypress APA Trackpad (cyapa)`: `id` может меняться). отключаем и включаем, по номеру и по имени:

```
$ xinput --disable 12
$ xinput --enable 'Cypress APA Trackpad (cyapa)'
```

2.

а курсор мыши можно скрыть, например, с помощью `xsetroot`.

Comment: С xinput не очень понятно, в нашем репозитории он есть только в виде xinput-calibrator, который после запуска делает вот так: https://pp.vk.me/c627723/v627723788/975c/TRaQYye5PuA.jpg. Я думал о том вчера, чтобы собрать его самому, когда смотрел один из вариантов с ним и он не заработал. Плюс, неясно, это обездвижит его в Xvesa, а потом задвигается ли он в dosbox? Он же, наверно, будет либо полностью обездвижен, либо полностью двигаться? Вот скрыть курсор пригодится как есть. Забрал.

Comment: Интересно, насколько сложно модифицировать драйвер мыши, который используется в Xvesa.

Comment: 1. пакет в репозитории [debian](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/xinput), man-страница [на x.org](www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xinput.1.html), git-репозиторий [апстрим-а](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xinput/). 2. *либо полностью обездвижен, либо полностью двигаться* — да.

Comment: Как мне узнать, какой драйвер мыши используется моей системой, чтобы однозначно идентифицировать его и иметь возможность гуглить "название драйвера source download" ? И как потом, в случае успешной модификации, заместить прежний драйвер своим?

Comment: *xserver* по умолчанию пишет лог в `/var/log`. возможно, *xvesa* по умолчанию делает то же самое. в логе *xserver* обычно пишет и про мышку тоже.

Comment: После запуска Xvesa в /var/log ничего похожего нет, к сожалению. Дальше сам покопаю. Хотя курсор уже скрыл и, в общем-то, все приемлемо выглядит, потому что со скрытым курсором выглядит так, будто курсор dosbox все-таки замкнут внутри своего региона. Можно, в принципе, и не мудрить.

Comment: судя по *man-у*, есть параметр `-verbose`, и судя по нему же, лог-файла нет, т.е., писать будет в `stdout` и/или `stderr`.

Comment: Ну, тогда можно элементарно перенаправить из файла стандартного вывода в свой. Попробую так.

Answer (score 2):

dosbox не сможет использовать мышь, если вы ее отключите совсем в Хvesa. Просто потому что dosbox не напрямую работает с мышью, а получает "мышиные" события от X сервера. Не обманывайтесь тем, что там якобы есть вторая мышь - это лишь второй рисунок той же самой мыши. Так что ваш третий вариант отпадает.

Я правильно понимаю, что у вас кроме dosbox ничего оконного не запущено? Почему бы тогда не использовать полноэкранный режим dosbox?

Comment: Потому что полноэкранный - это практично, а оконный - это красиво. Я сейчас прорабатываю второй вариант просто для того, чтобы было и потому, что могу. https://pp.vk.me/c627723/v627723788/96c6/LRD5ps3SAzQ.jpg

Comment: У меня и grub в таком стиле оформлен, хочу подобия.

Comment: Кстати, а насчет работы с мышью dosbox'а - а когда его запускаешь без Х-сервера, он откуда события мыши получает?